# SSH Access via tunneling

Tags: server, ssh, openssh, putty, tunnel

I have the following setup,

Machine A (Windows 10 & connected to ISP(X)) and Machine B (Windows 10 & connected to ISP(Y)). Both of these machines (A & B) do not have any direct connections. Machine A has access to Machine C (Linux Box running RHEL on cloud) and similarly, Machine B has access to Machine C.

Now keeping this Machine C as tunnel, is it possible to access a Linux machine (Ubuntu) running in Machine B (inside VirtualBox) from Machine A? If yes how can we do this? I guess this can be achieved via reverse ssh tunneling but not sure about the steps.

**To give more idea, the setup looks like the following**

```
                                   PUBLIC IP        SSH (Putty) (Machine C)
Machine A Windows 10 (192.168.1.2) --> ISP(49.xxx.xxx.xxx) ---> (34.xxx.xx.xxx)

                                 PUBLIC IP          SSH (Putty)  (Machine C)
Machine B Windows 10 (192.168.1.15) --> ISP(216.xxx.xxx.xxx) --->(34.xxx.xx.xxx)

Machine B Windows 10 (192.168.1.15) --> Virtual Box (192.168.1.100)
```

Now from Machine A, I wanted to access 192.168.1.100 (ubuntu Machine), how can I achieve this? There is only one machine (Machine C) where Machine A and Machine B has access to. Is there a way to do some tunneling and access 192.168.1.100 from Machine A?

Note: I do not have access to the router to do some forwarding. So I have to somehow make this happen by doing some tunneling.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. I can give the Linux commands, you'll have to lookup the equivalent configuration for whichever SSH clients you use on Windows.

From VM to B:

```
ssh -R localhost:2022:localhost:22 192.168.1.15
```

This will forward port 22 (presumably SSH) on the Ubuntu VM to port 2022 on 192.168.1.15.

From B to C:

```
ssh -R localhost:3022:localhost:2022 34.xxx.xx.xxx
```

This will forward the `localhost:2022` (which itself is from was forwarded by the previous command ran in the VM) to 3022 on C.

From A to C:

```
ssh -L 4022:localhost:3022 34.xxx.xx.xxx
```

This will forward the `localhost:3022` on C to A's 4022.

Thus we have a chain of forwarding:

- 4022 on A to
- 3022 on C to
- 2022 on B to
- 22 on the VM

Finally, on A:

```
ssh localhost:4022
```

This should connect to the VM.

- `-L` is `LocalForward` in [`ssh_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ssh_config.5)
- `-R` is `RemoteForward`

This chain can be shortened. For example, depending on the network settings involved, you could do, from B to C:

```
ssh -R :3022:192.168.1.15:22 34.xxx.xx.xxx
```

B will directly forward 3022 on C to 22 on the VM. And on A:

```
ssh 34.xxx.xx.xxx:3022
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and update you. I am using putty tool in windows.